# How to bind a Drop Down control with a collection using Query expression syntax?

Tags: linq

I am trying to bind a Dropdown with a collection but unable to write a proper query.

Lets say we have Employee collection. Employee type look like as follows:

```
public class Employee 
{ 
    public string  Name{get;set;} 
    public List<Department> Department { get; set; } 
    public string Company{get;set;} 
} 

public class Department 
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public string Location { get; set; } 
}
```

I am trying to bind a dropDown list with the unique department name (Department.Name) using query expression syntax. I have a collection of Employee type. The following doesn't seems to work.

```
dropDown1.DataSource = employees.Select(e => e.Department ).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out

```
dropDown1.DataSource = employees.SelectMany(e => e.Department.Select(d => d.Name)) // list of name lists
                            .Distinct() // unique names
                            .ToList();
```